# MonoTouch: UIImage.asJPEG needs a NSError object

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, uiimage, obsolete, nserror

To save a `UIImage` to a PNG or JPEG locally you call the `asPNG().Save(...)` function.

The `asPNG().Save()` function requires an `out NSError`

The problem is that you can no longer just create a blank NSError to pass in like this (`Obsolete`)

```
NSError err = new NSError();  //Obsolete
```

So, to use the Save() function in MonoTouch, how do we create an NSError() object now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET you do **not** have to initialize any `out` parameter (in contrast to `ref` parameters) since it's the *called* method job to do so.

E.g.

```
NSError err; // unitialized
UIImage img = ...;
img.AsPNG ().Save (url, true, our err);
if (err != null && err.Code != 0) {
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the default empty constructor for NSError is obsolete, not the NSError class itself. Feel free to specify the appropriate domain and code for your scenario and pass it in. Should work fine.